# TensorFlow Variables and Constants

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow , I am not able to understand the difference of variable and constant, I get the idea that we use variables for equations and constants for direct values , but why code #1 works only and why not code#2 and #3, and please explain in which cases we have to run our graph first(a) and then our variable(b) i.e

```
 (a) session.run(model)
 (b) print(session.run(y))
```

and in which case I can directly execute this command
i.e

```
print(session.run(y))
```

Code #1 :

```
x = tf.constant(35, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(x + 5, name='y')

model = tf.global_variables_initializer() 

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(y))
```

Code #2 :

```
x = tf.Variable(35, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(x + 5, name='y')

model = tf.global_variables_initializer() 

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(y))
```

Code #3 :

```
x = tf.constant(35, name='x')
y = tf.constant(x + 5, name='y')

model = tf.global_variables_initializer() 

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(y))
```

Comment: As of now (Sep 2019), code #2 works for tensorflow 1.14

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In TensorFlow the differences between constants and variables are that when you declare some [constant](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), its value can't be changed in the future (also the initialization should be with a value, **not with operation**).

Nevertheless, when you declare a [Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), you can change its value in the future with [tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) method (and the initialization can be achieved with a value or operation).

The function [tf.global_variables_initializer()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) initialises all variables in your code with the value passed as parameter, but it works in async mode, so doesn't work properly when dependencies exists between variables.

Your first code (#1) works properly because there is no dependencies on variable initialization and the constant is constructed with a value.

The second code (#2) doesn't work because of the async behavior of `tf.global_variables_initializer()`. You can fix it using [tf.variables_initializer()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer) as follows:

```
x = tf.Variable(35, name='x')
model_x = tf.variables_initializer([x])

y = tf.Variable(x + 5, name='y')
model_y = tf.variables_initializer([y])


with tf.Session() as session:
   session.run(model_x)
   session.run(model_y)
   print(session.run(y))
```

The third code (#3) doesn't work properly because you are trying to initialize a constant with an operation, that isn't possible. To solve it, an appropriate strategy is (#1).

Regarding to your last question. You need to run `(a) session.run(model)` when there are variables in your calculation graph `(b) print(session.run(y))`.

Comment: 1 more question , I came to know that the value of 'y' is computed when we use this statement 'session.run(y)' , so what was the purpose of running 'session.run(model)', didn't it execute the graph for value computation ?

Comment: When you `run` a variable, it returns the value of it. It's necessary to be initialized first, so it's a two phase process.

Comment: so this line 'model = tf.global_variables_initializer() ' means , i just assigned the graph/model to the variable named 'model' , but this graph executes / initializes the variables when  I run 'session.run(model)' , am i right?

Comment: Also worth mentioning, that one cannot save a `tf.constant` with `tf.train.Saver`

Answer (score 4):

I will point the difference when using eager execution.

As of Tensorflow 2.0.b1, `Variables` and `Constant` trigger different behaviours when using `tf.GradientTape`. Strangely, the official document is not verbal about it enough.

Let's look at the example code in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape

```py
x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
  z = y * y
dz_dx = g.gradient(z, x)  # 108.0 (4*x^3 at x = 3)
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)  # 6.0
del g  # Drop the reference to the tape
```

You had to *watch* `x` which is a `Constant`. **`GradientTape` does NOT automatically watch constants in the context.** Additionally, it can watch only one tensor per `GradientTape`. If you want to get gradients of multiple `Constant`s, you need to nest `GradientTape`s. For example,

```py
x = tf.constant(3.0)
x2 = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  g.watch(x)
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g2:
    g2.watch(x2)

    y = x * x
    y2 = y * x2

dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)       # 6
dy2_dx2 = g2.gradient(y2, x2)  # 9
del g, g2  # Drop the reference to the tape
```

On the other hand, **`Variable`s are automatically watched by `GradientTape`**.

> By default GradientTape will automatically watch any trainable variables that are accessed inside the context. Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape

So the above will look like,

```py
x = tf.Variable(3.0)
x2 = tf.Variable(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    y = x * x
    y2 = y * x2

dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)       # 6
dy2_dx2 = g.gradient(y2, x2)   # 9
del g  # Drop the reference to the tape
print(dy_dx)
print(dy2_dx2)
```

Of course, you can turn off the automatic watching by passing `watch_accessed_variables=False`. The examples may not be so practical but I hope this clears someone's confusion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can pass multiple tensors as an array into GradientTape.watch. Maybe the API changed since you wrote this

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look to the differences is:

1. tf.constant : are fixed values, and hence not trainable.
2. tf.Variable: these are tensors (arrays) that were initialized in a session and are trainable (with trainable i mean this can be optimized and can changed over time)