# Tensorflow: get predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to get predictions and learning network.

This is parameters of my network

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]), name="input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, y_train.shape[1]), name="y")
y_cls = tf.argmax(y, axis=1)

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([X_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[1]], stddev=0.05), name="weights", trainable=True)
bias = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[y_train.shape[1]], name="bias")

layer = tf.nn.relu_layer(X, weights, bias, name="relu_layer")
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer)
outs = tf.nn.relu(layer_1, name="outs")
y_pred = tf.argmax(outs, axis=1)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=layer_1, labels=y)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
acc = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_pred, y_cls), tf.float16)
predicted = tf.reduce_sum(acc)

learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
```

And try to get predictions with

```
n_epochs = 100
batch_size = 500
n_batches = int(np.ceil(1000 / batch_size))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    optimize(sess, training_op, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, epoch=20)
    print(sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: X_test}))
```

But it returns an error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I also try to use instead `y_pred` also `outs` and `layer_1` but it also returns this error.

How can I fix that and get values of predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code and I think the error you posted here is one of the least significant.

Lets go through your code and let me comment on some things. I hope this will be more helpful than just fixing the single `ValueError`.

You start with the definition of two placeholder variables `X`and `y` and define a new tensor `y_cls` as the `argmax` of `y`. From this I suspect that `y` is the collection of one-hot encoded ground truth class vectors (first axis for batch).

Then you go on and define weights and a bias. For the weights, you choose `tf.Variable` whereas for the bias you use `tf.constant`. I do not think that this was intentional and you in fact want the biases to be not trainable.
So notice: If you use `tf.constant`, you create a constant value that cannot be changed in the future. Therefore, the bias tensor will not be updated during training. Please read up on variables and constants in tensorflow. This questions might be a start: [TensorFlow Variables and Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745855/tensorflow-variables-and-constants)

Now you define the first layer:

```
layer = tf.nn.relu_layer(X, weights, bias, name="relu_layer")
```

What happens here is the following: For each vector `x` of length `X_train.shape[1]` in your batch, the value `u=x*W+b` is calculated and this results is passed through the `relu`function, which basically sets all values <0 to zero and leaves everything else as it is. So your output is `z=max(0,x*W+b)` where the maximum is taken elementwise. The output `z` has shape `(y_train.shape[1],)`. The `layer` tensor you defined has output of `tf.nn.relu_layer` has shape `(None, y_train.shape[1])` to account for the batch size.

You then define "funny" things:

```
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer)
outs = tf.nn.relu(layer_1, name="outs")
```

Written differently, you calculate `layer_1 = max(0,layer) = max(0,max(0,x*W+b))`. Because the relu function is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), this has no effect at all (except for creating a larger computation graph). So all the numbers in `layer_1` are the same as in `layer`.
You then do this again with `outs`. So `outs` is just the same as `layer_1` and `layer`.

Then you go on and add another activation function: the softmax. The application of this function is a bit hidden, because it happens at the same time as the `cross_entropy` is calculated. Combining a relu activation (or three) and a softmax in this way is "unconventional" to say the least. Interestingly, you use `layer_1` as your `logits` parameter and not `layer` or `outs`.

When you calculate your accuracy, you cast the output of `tf.equal(y_pred, y_cls)` to float16. Why float16? `tf.equal` returns a bool type and to do calculations with this mask, you surely have to cast it. But if you only want the sum, then casting to an `int` seems more reasonable. However, I suspect that you do not really want the sum as your "accuracy" but rather the ratio of true positives and the total number of presented samples. Have a look at [tf.metrics.accuracy!](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy)

In the second code snippet, you call some `optimize` function whose source code we do not know.

```
optimize(sess, training_op, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, epoch=20)
```

I expect that you run your `training_op` for `n_epochs` (but you pass epoch=20 to this function) with `X_train` as training data and ground truth labels `y_train`. Why you also pass `X_test` and `y_test` to the training method, I do not truly understand because usually you want to keep training and testing in two different steps.

Finally you call `sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={inp: X_test})`. In the feed_dict, you assign the placeholder `inp` the values of `X_test`. However, you have not defined a placeholder `inp` before so this code cannot run. I assume that you wanted to use `X_test` as input to your network and hence use it as values for the placeholder `X` you defined in the beginning.

I strongly advise you to read up more about neural networks and how to construct them and go through some tensorflow tutorials.

Then revise your whole code and feel free to come back with new questions when you are in trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's one of the best and comprehensible answer ever. I'm a new in tf and I've found this code like an example of text classification and try to use it. Thanks again for the clear explanation, I will try to write code from scratch and use your notes