# How I create a new class that inherits from tf.Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I would like to create a new class that is basically an array but with some extra attributes.

Specifically I would like to write a class, based on Tensorflow objects, that will describe time series data. As such it will have an associated time spacing (delta_t) and time vector
which I make with the `sample_times` property.

In python/numpy I do the following

```
import numpy as np
class TimeSeries(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_array, delta_t):
        self.initial_array = initial_array
        self.delta_t = delta_t

    @property
    def sample_times(self):
        return np.arange(self.initial_array.shape[0]) * self.delta_t
```

Is it possible to do something similar by by inheriting from tf.Tensor?
The reason for this is that I believe it would make life simpler as when
performing an analysis on these TimeSeries objects I could take advantage
of various tensorflow things like the `tf.function` decorator.

My basic attempt at a minimum working example is as follows and just attempts to be a sub-class of tf.Tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TFTimeSeries(tf.Tensor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

tf_ts = TFTimeSeries()
```

I get the following error upon instantiating `TFTimeSeries`

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'op', 'value_index', and 'dtype'
```

dtype is easy enough but the other two: 'op' and 'value_index' I am not sure what to do about.

I should say that my knowledge of tensorflow is not very advanced at all and I would appreciate any help with this thanks!

EDIT:

Hi @Filippo Grazioli and thanks for you answer! I think this is the best way forward. After thinking about the design of my code a bit more I don't think it's very Tensorflow the way I was thinking. So just making a class where attributes are Tensors makes more sense.

I will mark this as answered now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not passed op, value_index and dtype as arguments of `TFTimeSeries` when you instantiate your tf_ts object.

The same error would be thrown if you try to instantiate `tf.Tensor()` in the same fashion.

Regarding how to implement your `TFTimeSeries` class, `tf.Variable` and `tf.costant` might be interesting classes.

Here is their documentation:
[tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), [tf.costant](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant)

Here is a question in which their differences are explained:
[TensorFlow Variables and Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745855/tensorflow-variables-and-constants)

I am not sure if I correctly understood what you need to do, but this might be a starting point:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
import numpy as np

class TimeSeries(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_array, dt):
        self.tensor = tf.Variable(initial_array, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.dt = dt
        self.initial_array = initial_array 

    def sample_times(self):
        self.tensor = tf.Variable(np.arange(self.initial_array.shape[0]) * self.dt, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Hi @Filippo Grazioli and thanks for you answer! I think this is the best way forward.

After thinking about the design of my code a bit more I don't think it's very Tensorflow the way I was thinking. So just making a class where attributes are Tensors makes more sense