# Why model.fit() method of keras do not accept any tensor as feature or label argument, on the other hand it accepts numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

Last time when I was training a dnn model I noticed that When I try to train my model with tensor (dtype = float64) it always gives error but when I train the model with numpy array with same specs(shape, values, dtype) as tensor it shows no error. Why is it so

[Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l02c01_celsius_to_fahrenheit.ipynb)

For feature and labels as tensor replace numpy.arrys in 2nd script with:

```
celsius_q    = tf.Variable([-40, -10,  0,  8, 15, 22,  38],  tf.float64)
fahrenheit_a = tf.Variable([-40,  14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100],  tf.float64)
```

When using feature and label as tensor it shows this error:

```
Error: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>,
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should post the minimal executable code that causes the error

Comment: Don't use `tf.Variable` as input. Create a tensor using `tf.constant` instead, e.g., `celsius_q    = tf.constant([-40, -10,  0,  8, 15, 22,  38],  tf.float64)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.constant` for creating an input tensor in Tensorflow.
`tf.Variable` can be changed later so this type of tensor is not good for model input. Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44746203/20388268